# How to conveniently update 3 rows in DB table by elements of an array using PHP PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, loops, pdo

I’m learning PHP and PDO.
A bit confused with updating 3 rows in database by elements of array.
I have an array of data `$dateArray[$index]`, obtained by fetching from DB and calculating with another data. So finally, this array contains elements in such form:

`var_dump($dateArray[$index]);`

outputs

`string(10) "2018-07-24" string(10) "2018-07-11" string(10) "2018-07-23"`

A DB table looks like this:
[image]

Now I need to write them to DB (UPDATE stored values) in 3 columns: `day_remind1`, `day_remind2` and `day_remind3` and then display in the HTML table.

I suppose I should:

1. Make PDO prepared statement with UPDATE query;
2. Organize loop of `bindParam` statements assigning elements of `$dateArray[$index]` to fields.
3. Include `execute` in this loop to alternately update values of DB fields.

So this is how I do:

```
  $id = $_POST['id'];
  $day = $dateArray[$index];
  $sql = "UPDATE birthday_table SET day_remind1=:day, day_remind2=:day, day_remind3=:day WHERE id=:id";
  $stmt3 = $pdo->prepare($sql);

  foreach ($day as $dates=>$v) {
    $stmt3->bindParam(':day_remind1', $day);
    $stmt3->bindParam(':day_remind2', $day);
    $stmt3->bindParam(':day_remind3', $day);
    $stmt3->bindParam(':id', $id);
    $id = $v['id'];
    $stmt3->execute();
  }
  $db_handle = new DBController();
  // use AJAX variables column, editval, id containig user input 
  $result = $db_handle->executeUpdate("UPDATE birthday_table SET " . $_POST["column"] . " = '".$_POST["editval"]."' WHERE  id=".$_POST["id"]);
```

`

This doesn’t work, any data updated in DB, any error seen in console. Need clarification on how to fix my loop to solve my task.

Comment: what is your question/problem ?

Comment: @VaN, excuse me, updated my question, thanks

Comment: can you tell post data structure? so i can fix your code and give you problem running code because your code is not correct.

Comment: @KuldeepSingh, sorry, didn't understand, what should I tell exactly?

Comment: what type of data will come in $dateArray[$index] variable? Valid value should be 2018-07-26 but according to your question it seems something different.

Comment: @KuldeepSingh, An $dateArray[$index] array should contain 3 elements like 2018-07-24, 2018-07-11, 2018-07-23 which must be written in rows day_remind1, day_remind2, day_remind3 alternately (2018-07-24 in day_remind1, 2018-07-11 in day_remind2 etc)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't bind the query params correctly.

when you do `$stmt3->bindParam(':day_remind1', $day);`, that means you are trying to inject the `$day` variable in a placeholder called `:day_remind1`.

But your 3 placeholders in your query are all named `:day`.
Then you should edit your query to `$sql = "UPDATE birthday_table SET day_remind1=:day_remind1, day_remind2=:day_remind2, day_remind3=:day_remind3 WHERE id=:id";`

and remove the `:` when biding params:

```
$stmt3->bindParam('day_remind1', $day);
$stmt3->bindParam('day_remind2', $day);
$stmt3->bindParam('day_remind3', $day);
$stmt3->bindParam('id', $id);
```

Comment: edited my answer, you also need to remove `:` when binding params.

Comment: @VaN:- Bind Param value is also incorrect. It should be string but currently its array, as per current code.

Comment: @VaN, did, nothing changed